# How do I non-destructively mirror cuts with the Knife Tool?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, mirror, knife-tool

I'm looking for a way to make mirrored knife cuts in blender, be it via stock features or an addon. I want to preserve shape keys, UVs, bone weights, etc, so approaches such as the mirror modifier or the symmetrize option aren't applicable here, as they destroy some or all of this data.

Thanks!